# How to use self join in sequlize nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

How to use joins inside find function in sequlize. Below I have attached raw Mysql query. I'm new to sequelize help me in converting this raw query into sequelize format using 'include'.

```
SELECT child.name,child.position,child.image,child.description, parent.name AS parentName FROM `categories` child 
INNER JOIN `categories` parent ON
child.parentId = parent.id OR child.parentId = null
WHERE child.id = 9
```

[image: I have attached the table detail in this image]

Comment: why not just select twice?
`select * from 'categories' where id = 9`
`select name from 'categories' where id = child.parentId`
i think it is more efficient than self join

Comment: @王仁宏 can you help me this query with sequelize

Comment: no idea what you want, why not read their docs?